# F# Inserting an element multiple times to a list

Tags: recursion, f#

I am very new to `F#`, I am currently learning recursions.

```
let rec insert v i l =
    match i, l with
    | 0, xs -> v::xs
    | i, x::xs -> x::insert v (i - 1) xs;;
```

So this is the code for inserting `v` at ith position in list `l`.

I want to repeat this process so that I can insert `v` at every ith position of list `l`.

For example, if I compile the following code:

```
insert 7 2 [1..10];;
```

I want the result list to be:

```
[1; 2; 7; 3; 4; 7; 5; 6; 7; 7; 8; 7; 9; 10; 7]
```

Comment: Note that this is not really inserting a value into the original list, but creating a new list with the additional value in it.  The original list will be unchanged - this is important to understand in functional languages.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you should pay attention to F# compiler warnings. Incomplete pattern matches even show you the sample of input which is not covered by the patterns. In your case it's `(1,[])`. When you insert value only once, your code will break when the source list is empty. But when you want to insert value recursively many times, checking for empty list is very important, because it's a base case to short-circuit recursion.

Another thing you should consider when inserting value recursively many times is resetting the number of items you want to skip before inserting value again. You cannot do that if you don't store original value of `i` somewhere. You can introduce the 4th parameter to the function (`insert v i i l`), but a better solution is to use wrapper function which is not recursive. Wrapper function will capture both initial `i` value, and `v` which should be inserted. Note that captured values visible to inner recursive function

```
let insert v i l = // non-recursive wrapper function
    let rec skipAndInsert skip list =
        match skip, list with
        | _, [] -> [] // short-circuit recursion when there is no items left
        | 0, _ -> v::skipAndInsert i list // nothing to skip, insert value and reset skip
        | _, head::tail -> head::skipAndInsert (skip - 1) tail

    skipAndInsert i l

insert 7 2 [1..10] |> printfn "%A" // [1; 2; 3; 7; 4; 5; 6; 7; 7; 8; 9; 7; 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be used, when starting from your original code:

```
  let insert v i l =
    let rec insert2 v i p l =
      match i, l with
      | _, [] -> [v]
      | 0, xs -> v::(insert2 v p p xs)
      | i, x::xs -> x::insert2 v (i - 1) p xs
    insert2 v i i l
```

First, your original code had a Incomplete pattern matches warning. In F# it's important to fix the warnings, because they almost always refer to a regular case that would cause your code to fail. In case of your function it would be failing if you call it on empty list: `insert 1 1 []`

To handle the case you described it's enough to repeat the insertion of a value at position i again, when position is back to 0. And the end of recursion is when the list becomes empty. I introduced `p` variable to keep the original position at which you want to insert element. For that I introduced a private function `insert2`, just to keep the insert method signature unchanged.